# When using code-behind variables in an ASP.NET page, what is the difference between # and =?

Tags: asp.net

If you are just inserting information on a page, what are the differences, if any, between:

```
<%#Variable%>
```

and

```
<%=Variable%>
```

I've always used the # but a co-worker asked me today and I realized that, as far as I know, they are the same.  Surely, though, there must be *some* difference or why would MS provide both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%=Variable%>
```

is legacy from Classic ASP. Its short for

```
<% Response.Write(Variable) %>.
```

A new variation on that is

```
<%:Variable%>
```

which handles encoding it to HTML entities.

```
<%#Variable%>
```

is used in data binding.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  The upshot, in terms of variables is that the = will do the substitution without needing a "DataBind()" call.  The # does require such a call.

Answer (score 1):

http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx

I take no credit for this answer.